# open the current activity opended by the user

Tags: android, eclipse

I'm creating an android game, similar to 4pics1word.

my current status game:

- when the user entered the correct answer to question #1, he will proceed to question #2.
- I've used intent.putExtra, for the coins, on the question #1 class and in the question #2 class the passed data is read

my problem is:

- when the user reopen and/or exit the game and start the game, I want that question #2 will be automatically opened not the question #1
- from the passed data, I don't know how am i going to modify it. how to add/subtract the coins when the user use help or if the answer is correct

is there a possible solution to the stated problems?

code snippet would be a biiiig help.

can you help me? thank you so much in advance.

Comment: Store your current activity using shared preferences.. Or local database..

Comment: can you give me sample code?

Comment: I give hint shared preferences.google it.

Answer (score 0):

SharedPreferences values will persist across user sessions. Data in shared preferences will be persistent even though user closes the application.

You can get values from Shared preferences using getSharedPreferences() method.
You also need an editor to edit and save the changes in shared preferences.

***Here is simple code for store and retrieve the class name:***

```html
/******* Store the class name using SharedPreferences *******/
 
    SharedPreferences pref =  PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);
    Editor editor = pref.edit();
    editor.putString("any_key", "YourActivityName");  // Saving string
    editor.commit(); // commit changes
  
//retrive the class name..

SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);

String myactivity_name = prefs.getString("any_key", "DefaultActivityName"); // if no value in your key "DefaultActivityName" return. else your saved activity name returns.
```